# Point of Intersect between Line Centered in Square

Tags: intersection-theory

I need to find the point of intersection between some square `xy + N,N` where N is the size of the square and some line `x1,y1,x2,y2` where `x1,y1` lies on the center point of the square. Assume that the square is parallel to the x-axis & y-axis.

Related Questions:

1. [Intersection between a line section and square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280998/intersection-between-a-line-section-and-square)
2. [Coordinate of intersection between line and square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655369/coordinate-of-intersection-between-line-and-square?rq=1)

The answer in #1 provided essentially explains that you clamp one of the coordinates of the line to the square, which is inaccurate and produces incorrect results. The answer in #2 provides some obscure formula which isn't explained.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out the answer. You find the long-side of the triangle formed by the line `x1,y1,x2,y2` and multiple `x2,y2` by a scalar which is the difference between the long side of the triangle and `1/2` the length of the square.

```
line = x1,y1,x2,y2
square = x3,y3 + N,N

difference = (x2,y2) - (x3,y3)

// upper/lower quadrant of one quadrant in cartesian coordinate space.
if |difference.x| > |difference.y| then
    quadrant = 1
if |difference.x| <= |difference.y| then
    quadrant = 0

if quadrant == 0 then
    project.x = x2
    project.y = y3

if quadrant == 1 then
    project.x = x3
    project.y = y2

longside = |project.x + project.y - x1 + y1|
scalar = (N / 2) / longside
intersect = x1,y1 + (difference * scalar)
```

See example on Shadertoy: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/mtdyDn